# AoPS putnam 2003 A1 solution issue

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

I am having problems transferring and copying the data here. Take a look at [AOPS KENT MERRYFIELD ANSWER.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2325325&sid=4c8de8c3f7ca83a9a00ba6a405126aa5#p2325325)

I don't understand. He gets to:

$$a(k-r) + (a+1)r = n$$

But how does this show that there are exactly $n$ Ways?

---

From AoPs link:

> Let $n$ be a ﬁxed positive integer. How many ways are there to write $n$ as a sum of
>   positive integers, $
> n = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots a_k$
>   with $k$ an arbitrary positive integer and $a_1 \le a_2 \le \cdots \le a_k \le a_1 + 1$? For example, with $n = 4$, there are four ways: $4, 2 + 2, 1 + 1 + 2, 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$.

From Kent Merryfield answer:

> There are always exactly $n$ ways. Since each $a_i$ is either $a_1$ or $a_1 + 1$, we have the inequalities $ka_1 \le n < k(a_1 + 1)$, or $a_1 \le \frac nk  < a_1 + 1$. Hence, $a_1 = \lfloor(n/k)\rfloor$. For each positive integer$ k \le n$, let $n = ak + r$, where $a$ is a positive integer and $0 \le r < k$. This is simply the division algorithm, and $a \ge 1$ since $k \le n$. We then form the sum of $(k - r)$ copies of $a$ (this is at least one, since $r < k$) and $r$ copies of $a + 1$. The sum of this string of numbers is $a(k - r) + (a + 1)r = ak + r = n$. This string of numbers is unique for each $k$, and since we can do this for each $k$, there are exactly $n$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First he points out that each $a_i$ must be $a_1$ or $a_1+1$. This implies that for any given number $k$ of terms, $a_1$ must be $\lfloor n/k\rfloor$. In other words, once you know the number of terms, you know what $a_1$ must be. Thus, for some $r<k$ there must be $r$ terms that are $a_1+1$ and $k-r$ that are $a_1$. (We must have $r<k$, since the first term has to be $a_1$. He then shows that there is only one choice of $r$ that gives you a solution for this value of $k$.

Finally, there are exactly $n$ possible choices of $k$. Clearly $k$ is a positive integer, and since $1\le a_1=\lfloor n/k\rfloor$, we must have $k\le n$. Thus, there is one solution for each of the $n$ possible numbers of terms: $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: He just uses $a$ generally though  not $a_1$ ?

Comment: @Drizzy: Yes, once he’s established that $a_1$ is completely determined by $n$ and $k$, he drops the subscript in order to simplify the notation and calls it simply $a$.

Comment: How can he let $n = a_1 k + r$ what is the reason he is allowed to do that?

Comment: @Drizzy: The division algorithm. When you divide $n$ by $k$, you get a quotient of $a_1$ and a remainder of $r$, where $0\le r<k$, and that means that $n-r=a_1k$, or $n=a_1k+r$.

Comment: Okay, that part seems clear. But how do you form as he says: (k-r) copies of $a_1$ ?  How to reach this conclusion?

Comment: @Drizzy: Suppose that you made each of the terms equal to $a_1$; then the sum would be $ka_1$. But $n=ka_1+r$, so you need to increase $r$ of the terms by $1$ to get a total of $n$. That will give you $r$ terms that are $a_1+1$, and the rest (i.e., the other $k-r$) will still be $a_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, $n = ka_1 + r$. How does increasing $r$ of the terms by $1$ each time get you a total of $n$?

Comment: @Lebes: You're starting with $k$ terms, each of which is $a_1$. Their sum is $ka_1$. If you now increase the last $r$ of them by $1$ each, you increase their total by $r\cdot 1=r$ to get $ka_1+r$, which is $n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Then if you increase some of them by $r$. How is it: $(k - r)$? Why the negative $r?$

Comment: @Lebes: Eh? You're not increasing any of them by $r$: you're increasing $r$ of them by $1$ each. There are $k$ of them altogether, so there must be $k-r$ that are *not* being increased. As a result you have $k-r$ that are $a_1$ and $r$ that are $a_1+1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, So you are adding $a_1 + 1$ $r$ times?

Comment: @Lebes: Each of the $r$ terms $a_{k_r+1},a_{k_r+2},\ldots,a_k$ is equal to $a_1+1$. This is quite clearly, if concisely, explained in the answer quoted in the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I really do not understand Kent's answer. The steps are too vague for someone with as much knowledge as mine to pick up. Let me retry:


So he is taking $r(a_1 + 1)$? Right?

Comment: @Lebes: This really isn’t the place to work through it a piece at a time. Try reading the write-up in the $2003$ solutions available [here](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/); it’s a slightly different explanation of essentially the same idea and might help you. Then if you have a specific question about it, you could make it a new question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I looked there, it seems better, I still do have questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142431/how-does-the-sequence-have-n-possibilities would you mind considering the question?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two admissible terms for a given starting value $a$, $a$ and $a+1$.

So $n=pa+q(a+1)=(p+q)a+q$

$p+q$ is the total number of terms in the sum. Call that $k=p+q$.

Unless all terms of the sum are equal, some are greater than the mean and some are less, but they have to differ by one. It follows that $a=[n/k]$. This also covers the case when all terms are equal.

$n=k[n/k]+q$

So $q=n-k[n/k]=n \% k$

$n=k[n/k]+n\%k$

$q$ is unique by the division algorithm applied to $n$ and $k$. There is one possible sum for each $k$ and $k$ may take on values from 1 to $n$. So there are $n$  ways for each $n$.