# How does the sequence have $n$ possibilities?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

From: [Solution 2003 A1](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2003s.pdf) and problem: [Problem 2003 A1](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2003.pdf)

The first part of the solution is fine: The problem is here:

[image]

**The issue is this:**

(1) They say "once $a_1$ is fixed..." there are $k$ different possibilities..."

- The confusion is: How does the ensure $k$ different possibilties?

(2) Then --> If $i$ is the last integer such that $a_i = a_1$ then sum $= ka_1 + (i - 1)$.

- How and where do they get this idea from?

(3) They state possible values of $i$ are: $i = 1, ... k$. Then this means: sum $= ka_1 + 0$ or sum $= ka_1 + 3$.

- This leads to $k$ answers? But how can the sum sum $ka_1 + 1$ and $ka_1 + 2$ at the **same time?**

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Once $a_1$ is fixed there are k possibilities for the sum $a_1+....+a_k$ depending on how many are equal to $a_1+1$(which is at least 0 and at most $k-1$) so $k$ sums.

(2) This is wrong however if $i$ is the last such that $a_i=a_1$ then the sum is $ka_1+k-i$

(3) This means that given our $k$ and $a_1$ we can get the $k$ sums putting $i=1,2,...,k$ which are $ka_1+k-1,ka_1+k-2,....,ka_1$ Due to choosing our $a_1$ such that $ka_1\le n\le ka_1+k-1$ exactly one of these sums is equal to $n$.

So we have proven that given a $k$ s.t. $1\le k\le n$ we have a unique way to write $a_1+a_2+...+a_k$. Because when we fix $k$ $a_1$ is unique and the other numbers are uniquely determined by how many are equal to $a_1$ and how many are $a_1+1$